# Конкатенация (склеивание) нескольких значений в одну строку

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как в XAML можно склеить несколько значений в одну строку? Вот сейчас выводит Пользователей в команде : 33. Хочу еще название команды добавить. SelectedTeams.TeamName.
Должно получиться Пользователей в команде Админов: 33. 
Хочу это реализовать без темплетов, или создания автосвойств и тд. Чисто в xaml.

```
<GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=UsersToTeams.Count}" HeaderStringFormat="Пользователей в команде : {0}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" FontSize="15">
```

Comment: `без темплетов` - что вы подразумеваете под `темплет`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ <DataTemplate><StackPanel>3 текстблока допустим</StackPanel></DataTemplate> Вот хочу кокатенацией чисто это реализовать, а не дататемплатами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Пользователей в команде"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding SelectedTeams.TeamName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Run Text=":"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding UsersToTeams.Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Да, именно то что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: Что интересно, у каждого Run можно отдельно изменить размер/цвет/начертание шрифта

Comment: А добавлять небольшие проверки можно сюда? Типо если А=20 тогда использовать другое значение, допустим не TeamName, TeamRole.

Comment: Небольшие проверки на равенство можно сделать с помощью триггеров